# Implement Share Count In React With React-Share Package

Tags: reactjs, react-share

I'm trying to implement share count with the react-share package but I still can't find a way around it. I used the Component everywhere in the app, and and every time I get 0 in the count although I share the URL several times.
This is the Facebook component I tried:

```
<FacebookShareButton url={currentPostUrl} quote='This is MSN' >
      <FacebookIcon size={30} borderRadius={15} />
             <FacebookShareCount url={"https://www.example.com/"}>
                    {shareCount => <div>{shareCount}</div>}
             </FacebookShareCount>  
</FacebookShareButton>
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you!